# XFCE default applications menu XML file

Tags: xfce4

Do anybody know where do we have to put the XML file `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu` for being customized and loaded? I've tested all the possibilities (`/home/user/.config`, `/home/user/.xfce4/desktop`, etc.) but the official docummentation in the XFCE wiki is not clear.

Anybody?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way the menu system works is very convoluted.  Trying to manually change it will give you brain damage.  There are several menu editing utilities available, alacarte and menulibre, among others, that will provide a simple GUI interface for modifying the menu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3

Comment: If you really want to tackle it by hand, start here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those interested. Freedesktop specifies the menus in [this document](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/):

I have removed all the files under `/etc/xdg/menus`, and created only `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu`, so no files are merged between different desktop environments.

To show only the .desktop entries I want, I have created two directories and declared them in the menufile:

```
<AppDir>/usr/share/folder/applications/launchers</AppDir>
<DirectoryDir>/usr/share/folder/applications/directories</DirectoryDir>
```

The categories inside the .desktop files have been checked to match.

Cheers!